# Clear and exit button

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, uitextfield, exit

I have 2 questions.

1) How can I clear all entered textfields and label text when pressed clear button ?

2) How can I exit from application when pressed exit button ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1) How can I clear all entered textfields and label text when pressed clear button ?
```

For Your Questions 1 Remove all Subview form any views

```
[self.view.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

and if you Only looking to clear the text inti UILabel or UITextField

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
   yourFirstTxtField.text=@"";
   yourLabelField.text=@""
}
```

And

```
2) How can I exit from application when pressed exit button ?
```

And for The Second one use the [How do I programmatically quit my iOS application?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1561.html)On the iPhone App Development there is no concept of quitting an app. 
The only action that should cause an app to quit is touching the Home button on the phone

And Also Apple provide [Human Interface Guidelines show something like this.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/MobileHIG.pdf)

**Don’t Quit Programmatically**

But there is some way to do this like  `exit(0)`

and `[[NSThread mainThread] exit]`, andI have not tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate through all `textfields and labels` as :

```
 for (UIView *common in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([common isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] || [common isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            commonTextField.text = @"";
        }
    }
```

Answer 2 : There is now way to exit your application. Because apple does not allow top focibly exit from an app.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This will clear all labels. Even others which you are using to indicate some information to the user. Please make sure you handle that situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)fnClear{
tf1.text = @"";
..
lbl1.text = @"";
..
}
```

You cannot exit from an application on button click. It is not recommended by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

For **First Que**

You can Create One IBAction For Button Click and there In action you put all Your Textfild and UILableVariable as a nil or @"" like bellow Example:-

```
-(IBAction)Clear
{
   txtFirstName.text=@"";
   lblFirst.text=@""
}
```

For **Second Que**

there Apple not Provide any method you can Implement in your Project for out of app you must press Home button.